# Treeview -- How to scroll until selected item is on top?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, treeview

I'm Working On A personal file browser app for a year, and I'm Trying to Focus was folder I choose.

For instance, if I say my default folder is C: \ Users \ Me Then It Will Automatically expand C, Then Users, etc. ...

In the end, I select the 'Me' folder, I did not manage to scroll to Automatically so That I can see it on top of my
list. Does anybody Have an idea?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Have u look at this:
[Scroll WPF Listview to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211971/scroll-wpf-listview-to-specific-line)

[Scroll a new item in a ItemsControl into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615568/wpf-scroll-into-view-a-new-item-in-a-itemscontrol)

Comment: This is working with a listview, not a treeview. This is quite different, there is no ScrollIntoView method with treeview...