# WPF Treeview - How can I scroll the treeview until the selected item is on top?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

I am currently working on an wpf application where I have a treeview with a hierarchichal datatemplate with my own object "Workstep".

What I want to do:

I want to hit a specific key (letter) and bring the first workstep with the a name starting with that letter on top of my treeview

Why:

Because the treeview is large and scrolling until the specific letter takes a lot of time in the production area of the company i am working for

My work until now:
In my viewmodel I catch the keydown event of my treeview with the following method (watch out-> the "K" is just a example letter to show what I mean):

```
Public Sub TreeViewKeyDown(sender as Object, e as KeyEventArgs)
   if e IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Key = Key.K Then
      For Each w In myTree
         If w.Name.StartsWith("K") Then
           Dim treeViewItem As TreeViewItem = CType(m_TreeViewInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(w), TreeViewItem)
         treeViewItem.BringIntoView()  
         End If
      Next
   End If
```

The problem with my current solution is that my items come to view but are not on top of my treeview, as I would like to have.

Does anybody have a clue how to do that?

(btw: Didn't get the answer through this article: [Treeview -- How to scroll until selected item is on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068922/treeview-how-to-scroll-until-selected-item-is-on-top))