# WPF Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid: Select property

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I want to set the focus on the first item of the property grid. So after adding an object and bind it to the PropertyGrid, you can change the first property.

I tried this, but dont work:

```
propertyGrid.Focus();
propertyGrid.SelectedProperty = propertyGrid.Properties[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no built-in solution to this.

My suggested solution is more like a Workaround, but it should properly Visual-Select the `SelectedProperty` if it's been set on codebehind.

First of all, we need some **Extensions**:

```
 public static class Extensions {
    public static T GetDescendantByType<T>(this Visual element) where T : class {
      if (element == null) {
        return default(T);
      }
      if (element.GetType() == typeof(T)) {
        return element as T;
      }
      T foundElement = null;
      if (element is FrameworkElement) {
        (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++) {
        var visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
        foundElement = visual.GetDescendantByType<T>();
        if (foundElement != null) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return foundElement;
    }

    public static void BringItemIntoView(this ItemsControl itemsControl, object item) {
      var generator = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator;

      if (!TryBringContainerIntoView(generator, item)) {
        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
          switch (generator.Status) {
            case GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated:
              TryBringContainerIntoView(generator, item);
              break;
            case GeneratorStatus.Error:
              generator.StatusChanged -= handler;
              break;
            case GeneratorStatus.GeneratingContainers:
              return;
            case GeneratorStatus.NotStarted:
              return;
            default:
              break;
          }
        };

        generator.StatusChanged += handler;
      }
    }

    private static bool TryBringContainerIntoView(ItemContainerGenerator generator, object item) {
      var container = generator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;
      if (container != null) {
        container.BringIntoView();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

  }
```

After this, you can easily do the following:

```
//Register to the SelectedPropertyItemChanged-Event
this._propertyGrid.SelectedPropertyItemChanged += this.PropertyGridSelectedPropertyItemChanged;
//Set any Property by index
this._propertyGrid.SelectedProperty = this._propertyGrid.Properties[3];
```

Finally do the magically Highlighting

```
private void PropertyGridSelectedPropertyItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<PropertyItemBase> e) {
      var pic = this._propertyGrid.GetDescendantByType<PropertyItemsControl>();
      pic.BringItemIntoView(e.NewValue);
      // UPDATE -> Move Focus to ValueBox
      FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(pic,e.NewValue);
      var xx = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
      xx?.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
```

**Closure**

The key to everything here is, knowing about the `PropertyItemsControl` which is an ItemsControl holding all the Properties.

Hope this helps!

**Credits**

[Bring ItemsControl into view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615626/4558029)
[Get Nested element from a Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850876/4558029)

Comment: The item is selected, but i cannot directly set the value by keyboard, had to press TAB so i can edit

Comment: @Suplanus Ive modified my Code to match you needs. Now the Value-Box is Focused and ready for input